# I added some files in my ios project but they are not showing up in XCode project navigator [ XCode 13.2 ]

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, runner

I added a directory indside **Runner** as shown

[image]

But directory is not showing up in *project navigator*

[image]

I copied and pasted directory inside it.

How can I resolve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Files do not show in **XCode Project navigator** because they *must be* added from **outside** of ***XCode***.

---

### It woluld be better if you add them from inside project navigator(XCode).

1. Goto the navigator and Right-click on any directory in which you want to add files/folder.
2. Click on `Add Files to <ProjectName>`

[image]

3. Now Select files/folder that ou want to add
4. then click `Add`.

[image]

### Now all Files/Directories (that you have selected) will be added in your project.